# Update the XML nodes based on the node value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my table I have `col 1 ,col 2 ,col 3`. The `col 3` has the XML stored. I want update the `Name,Signedby,userid,title,status,lastmodified` nodes based on "Name" node.

XML File:

```
<SignatureSummary>
  <SectionList>
    <Section>
       <Name>A</Name>
       <SignedBy></SignedBy>
       <UserId></UserId>
       <Title></Title>
       <Status></Status>
       <LastModifiedOn></LastModifiedOn>
    </Section>
    <Section>
       <Name>B</Name>
       <SignedBy />
       <UserId />
       <Title />
       <Status />
       <LastModifiedOn />
    </Section> 
  </SectionList>
</SignatureSummary>
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What should be if Name in XML does not exists in your table? If you need to be returned only valid names, you can write simple SELECT with FOR XML query which will get data from your table. If you need all data to be returned, you will need XML to be processed (performance is worse in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
     Col1, Col2,
     Section.value('(Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS 'Name',
     Section.value('(SignedBy)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS 'SignedBy',
     Section.value('(UserId)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS 'UserId',
     Section.value('(Title)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS 'Title',
     Section.value('(Status)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS 'Status',
     Section.value('(LastModifiedOn)[1]', 'DATETIME') AS 'Last Modified On'
FROM
     dbo.YourTable
CROSS APPLY
     Col3.nodes('/SignatureSummary/SectionList/Section') AS Sig(Section)
```